# power supply regulator output current

Tags: power-supply, power

Here i have attached basic power regulator block diagram. The voltage regulator input (Vin) get 5V from adapter and gives ouput as 3.3V maximum of 3Amps load current.My question and understanding is inside of the regulator(amplifier) generates 3 amps current getting input of these amplifiers i.e base current of the amplifier is very less (EX: some mAmps).Its not driven 3Amps from adapter and give to Regulator output. Am i correct?[image]

Answer (score 1):

With a linear regulator, yes, it is drawing 3A from the adapter (and burning 5.1W). With a switching regulator it is drawing *at least* \${{3.3\text{V}\cdot3\text{A}}\over{5\text{V}}}=1.98\text{A}\$. No amplifier can add power on its own; it must *always* be drawn from somewhere else.

Comment: thanks for quick response. So we are only using Regulators for voltage conversion and act as driver to give require load current smoothly. Is it correct?

Comment: The "smoothly" part depends on the capacitors around the regulator, but yes.

Comment: could you please suggest me if you have any link/share to clarify myself in depth knowledge?

Answer (score 0):

You write: "Here i have attached basic power regulator block diagram." which implies that if it's really a switching **POWER** regulator and its output supplies:

$$ \text{P}=\text{EI = 3.3V} \times \text{3A} = \text { 9.9 watts}$$

to the load, its [the regulator's] input must draw at least:

$$ \text{I} = \frac{\text{P}}{\text{E}} = \frac{\text{9.9W}}{\text{5V}} = \text{1.98 amperes} $$

from the source in order to transfer the 9.9 watts the load needs, from the source to the load.

If the regulator is running at 85% efficiency when it's supplying 9.9 watts to the load, then the regulator's input must be taking:

$$ \text{Pin} =\frac{\text{9.9W}} {0.85} \approx \text{11.65 watts} $$

from the source.

Then, since the total power from the source is 11.65 watts and, since the load is consuming 9.9 watts of that 11.65 watts, the difference is:

$$ \text{Preg} = \text{Ps - Pl} = \text{11.65W - 9.9W} = \text{1.75 watts} $$

which the regulator must be using for its own purposes.

If, however, what you posted was a diagram of a **LINEAR** regulator, things will be much different since the regulator will look like an automatically adjustable rheostat in series between the source and the load.

As such, let's say we have - as you've shown - a 5 volt source and a 3.3volt load which wants to have 3 amperes flowing through itself.

Since current is everywhere the same in a series circuit, the 5 volt source will  push 3 amperes through both the regulator and the load, with the regulator dropping the 5 volts down to 3.3 for the load.

Then, since the regulator will drop the difference between 5 volts and 3.3 volts across itself with 3 amperes flowing through itself, it'll dissipate:

$$ \text{P} = \text {(Vs-Vl)}\times\text{I} =  \text {1.7V}\times\text{3.3A} = \text{5.6 watts}$$

Which is pretty wasteful compared to the switcher.

One caveat is that if you've shown  a conventional linear regulator, (as opposed to a low-dropout (LDO) regulator), it probably won't work because the input-output differential voltage (headroom) is too small.  LDOs can get down to a couple hundred millivolts or so of headroom, so they'll work. But, you'll still pay the wasted energy price